# A Question about Pointed Cones

Tags: convex-analysis, dual-cone

I have the following problem

Prove that if $X$ is a pointed cone then there exists a vector $c$ such that $c^Tx>0$ for all nonzero $x \in X$.

For this, I seem to have a simple solution as follows:

Suppose to the contrary that, $c^Tx \le 0$ for every $c \in \mathbb R^n$ and for all nonzero $x \in X$. That means, if we fix a nonzero vector $d \in \mathbb R^n$ then $d^Tx \le 0$ and $(-d)^Tx \le 0$ for all nonzero $x \in X$. Therefore, $d^Tx \le 0 \le d^Tx$ which implies $d^Tx=0$. Hence, $X$ contains a hyperplane $d^T x= 0$ i.e. $X$ contains a straight line which is a not pointed cone. It contradicts to our assumption.

Any comment is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there anybody here?

Answer (score 0):

Intuition, It suggests that the Cone "Opening" is less than 180 Degrees which means it is pointed.

Suppose to the contrary that $ \forall d \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \; {d}^{T} x \le 0 $ for any $ x \in X $.

Specifically one could chose $ d \neq 0 $ which yields:

$$ {d}^{T} x \le 0, \; -{d}^{T} x \le 0 $$

Assuming the Cone $ X $ includes items besides the zero point then:

$$ {d}^{T} x \leq 0 \Rightarrow -{d}^{T} x \geq 0 $$

Yet by out assumption $ -{d}^{T} x \leq 0 $ hence $ {d}^{T} x = 0 $ which suggests the set $ \left\{ x \mid {d}^{T} x = 0 \right\} \subseteq X $, namely there is an Hyperplane inside $ X $ which suggests there is a line in $ X $ which is a contradiction to the assumption $ X $ is pointed Cone.